# Grouping and formatting array to write to CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv, merge

I am using PHP to write an array to CSV but need some help formatting the data. Currently it is:

```
Array
(
    [YYYY-MM-DD] => Array
        (
            [1] => INT
            [2] => INT
            [3] => INT
        )

    [YYYY-MM-DD] => Array
        (
            [1] => INT
            [2] => INT
            [3] => INT
        )
)
```

I would like to write to a CSV like:

```
YYYY-MM-DD, INT, INT, INT
YYYY-MM-DD, INT, INT, INT
```

Comment: Your question is too incomplete. It doesn't provide full context . Post the code you tried till now

Comment: What you having problems with? it looks trivial, there's a few ways to do it, in just a couple of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know how to write CSV to a file, since you said you're already doing that, here's a way to merge your keys into your values array before writing.

```
foreach ($array as $date => $ints) {
    fputcsv($file, array_merge([$date], $ints));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a PHP output (didn't really understand your CSV problem), you can do it like this :

```
    $arr1 = array("2017-02-12" => array(1 => "INT1", 2 => "INT2", 3 => "INT3"),
                    "2017-04-30" => array(1 => "INT1", 2 => "INT2", 3 => "INT3"),
                    "2017-11-18" => array(1 => "INT1", 2 => "INT2", 3 => "INT3"));


    foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
        $ints = "";
        foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
            $ints = $ints.", ".$value2;
        }
        echo $key.$ints."\n";
    }

// Output : 
2017-02-12, INT1, INT2, INT3
2017-04-30, INT1, INT2, INT3
2017-11-18, INT1, INT2, INT3
```

Demonstration here : https://3v4l.org/mBcWi